# How do I use css media queries with an iframe?

Tags: css, iframe, fancybox, media-queries

I have a page that loads an iFrame (fancybox). My CSS media queries work fine on the parent pages but when the content is called within the iFrame, the media queries don't work. (the content within the iFrame has it's own stylesheet).

How do i get the media queries to work within the iFrame? 
FYI - My width and height is being set by the javascript that calls 'fancybox' which creates the iFrame and is set using percentages.

Answer (score 2):

Unless I'm very much mistaken, you have very little 'outside' control over the contents of an iframe with *your* CSS. I think you're kind of out of luck.

Comment: If the Iframe is loading your CSS as well, should it not work? I'm having the same issue with it not reading the css the same. I could load the homepage in an iframe on the homepage, and the iframe homepage wouldn't have the same style as the regular homepage.